# Achieve same results without common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My SQL code produce per_month, per_month min, per_month max and per_month standard deviation. But i have done it with CTE. now i want to do without CTE.

```
;WITH QTY_T AS(
SELECT 
            YEAR(SHIP_DATE) [Year], 
            MONTH(SHIP_DATE) [Month], 
            T1.PLANT AS PLANTS,
            WC AS W_C,
            T2.SHIP_TO AS SHIP_TO,
            T1.PARTS AS PARTS,
            SUM([QTY_MII]) AS [QTY_MONTH]
    FROM TABLE1 T1
            INNER JOIN 
                TABLE2 T2
                ON
                T2.OBD = T1.OBD
            INNER JOIN
                TABLE3 T3
                ON T1.OBD=T3.OBD AND T1.ITEM = T3.ITEM AND T1.PLANT =  T3.PLANT
            INNER JOIN
                TABLE4 T4
                ON T3.SHIP_LBL = T4.HU_CODE AND T4.STATUS ='SHIPPED'AND T4.PLANT = T3.PLANT
    GROUP BY 
                T1.PLANT,WC,SHIP_TO,T1.PARTS,YEAR(SHIP_DATE),MONTH(SHIP_DATE)
) SELECT  
        PLANTS,W_C,PARTS,SHIP_TO,
        ROUND(AVG(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH,
        ROUND(MIN(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH_MIN,
        ROUND(MAX(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH_MAX,
        ROUND(AVG(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH_AVG,
        ROUND(STDEV(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH_STD
   FROM QTY_T
   GROUP BY PLANTS,W_C,QTY_T.SHIP_TO,QTY_T.PARTS
```

Comment: without CTE,Subquery?

Comment: I'd like to ask: Why?

Comment: CTE is actually a great way of structuring your queries so feel free to use it (it is even more readable then the subqueries).

Comment: i was told CTE will cause performance issues, that's why..in fact i like to use CTE

Answer (score 0):

you can use `subquery` without cte

```
SELECT  
    PLANTS,W_C,PARTS,SHIP_TO,
    ROUND(AVG(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH,
    ROUND(MIN(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH_MIN,
    ROUND(MAX(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH_MAX,
    ROUND(AVG(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH_AVG,
    ROUND(STDEV(QTY_MONTH),3) AS QTY_SHIPPED_PER_MONTH_STD
FROM (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(SHIP_DATE) [Year], 
        MONTH(SHIP_DATE) [Month], 
        T1.PLANT AS PLANTS,
        WC AS W_C,
        T2.SHIP_TO AS SHIP_TO,
        T1.PARTS AS PARTS,
        SUM([QTY_MII]) AS [QTY_MONTH]
    FROM TABLE1 T1
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.OBD = T1.OBD
        INNER JOINTABLE3 T3 ON T1.OBD=T3.OBD AND T1.ITEM = T3.ITEM AND T1.PLANT =  T3.PLANT
        INNER JOIN TABLE4 T4 ON T3.SHIP_LBL = T4.HU_CODE AND T4.STATUS ='SHIPPED'AND T4.PLANT = T3.PLANT
    GROUP BY 
        PLANT,WC,SHIP_TO,T1.PARTS,YEAR(SHIP_DATE),MONTH(SHIP_DATE)
) as QTY_T
GROUP BY PLANTS,W_C,QTY_T.SHIP_TO,QTY_T.PARTS
```

Comment: thanks!..your query gives me the same results. Cheers..now it looks simple :)